# For each new year from date straing PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

How can I create a result, in either `PHP` or `MySQL` which will show the year 2005, as example, and sum all results

<kbd>Example input</kbd>

```
-------------------------
Date       \    Quantiti
-------------------------
12-05-2005 \      5
-------------------------
23-08-2005 \      8
-------------------------
11-02-2006 \      4
-------------------------
26-09-2006 \      2
-------------------------
```

<kbd>Example ouput</kbd>

```
---------------------------
year    \    Total
---------------------------
2005    \     13
---------------------------
2006    \     6
---------------------------
```

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY date DESC"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $date = $row["date"];
        $quantiti = $row["quantiti"];

        // here i need code for each new year 
    }
    } else {


    }
?>
```

Comment: The big letters are for headers. Could you please edit your question and make it readable.

Comment: You should take a look at `YEAR()` and `SUM()`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SUM to sumup the quantity and GROUP BY to group results by year.

A sql query for your needs would be:

```
SELECT YEAR(Date), SUM(Quantiti) 
FROM mytaple
GROUP BY YEAR(Date)
```

So your code would be:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT YEAR(Date) as y, SUM(Quantiti) as q FROM mytaple GROUP BY YEAR(Date)"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $date[] = $row["y"];
        $quantiti[] = $row["q"];
    }
for($i<0; $i<count($date);$i++) {
        echo $date[$i]."/".$quantiti[$i];
    }
    } else {


    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks the idea was  'GROUP BY'.  But the issue is i don't know how to adapt it in my code in PHP  :(

Comment: Thank you its working now, appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You can `SUM()` all the quantyties which have the same year by grouping the years, using `GROUP BY YEAR(date)`. A simple query like this should do the job

```
SELECT SUM(Quantiti) as `total`, 
       YEAR(date) as `year` 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY YEAR(date)
```

Note that the returning result is named `total` and `year`, as per your example output.

Answer (score -1):

Group by With year and Month will achieve this

> GROUP BY YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date)